# Nginx + Passenger

Tags: nginx, passenger

Hello i have one question.. i can succesfully install webserver with multiple vhost rails applications but now i want add passenger support to existed nginx server (which is configured via ISPConfig).. the problem is that if i let passenger to download and compile nginx
`passenger-install-nginx-module` it have configuration files in /opt/nginx but ISPConfig is using /etc/nginx, passenger is asking where nginx have to be installed but i dont know what to type for /etc/nginx configuration path. Another way im thinking is let apt-get install nginx but in that case i dont know how to add passenger.. i read about nginx-full but that download few bytes to my linux and does not work and from debian wiki https://wiki.debian.org/Nginx it does not contain passenger module anyway.. im using Ubuntu, what can i do ? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run 'nginx -V', that will tell you what configure arguments were used to compile your distribution's Nginx. Pass those same arguments to passenger-install-nginx-module.

Comment: thank you ! Another solution i thought about is using symlinks (from /etc to /opt).. i dont know what is better solution

Answer (score 1):

when i'm install passenger installer ask me where put nginx (default /opt/nginx/). try reinstall passenger-install-nginx-module and read what installer write.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have Nginx there is no need to install anything but passenger stand-alone. You can just proxy all requests to this site's rails code to the passenger stand-alone instance using a vhost in your existing nginx installation. Here is a good place to start:

https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/deploy/standalone/reverse_proxy.html

Answer (score 0):

You can change the config locations and update your nginx start up script (/etc/init.d/nginx) to point to the config directory.

if you are installing the passenger-nginx module then make sure the apt-get package version of nginx is removed and also clean up the file /etc/init.d/nginx for a clean install.

You can also install nginx from the apt-get repository (you don't have to make a start-up script with this) re-use the nginx.conf file from the passenger-nginx-module and plug-in the passenger settings in the new config file.

happy nginxing...